# Executing user created function safely within Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

I would like to add a feature to my site that gives users the ability to create custom JavaScript functions that would run on a Node.js server. Users would upload the JS function and I would eval to code and use it's return value somehow on the server. However, this is an obvious security hole. Is there someway in JavaScript/ Node.js to only allow a function to have scope to only parameters given to it? I don't want it to have access to variables else where in the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: eval is a great security risk on the browser itself, how much more on the server?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at:

[vm.runInNewContext(code, [sandbox], [filename])](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_filename)

Comment: Thanks, this opens up a world of possibilities.

Comment: @Eddie: Any possibility that you could accept his answer if it worked for you?